# Prove or refute that $\frac{t^a-1}{t^b-1}$ is not a integer if $a \mod b \neq 0$

Tags: number-theory, computer-science

Hi guys in my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45629/prove-or-refute-that-fracta-1tb-1-has-more-than-100-digits-if-a-mod-b) I got the wrong idea maybe because a poor problem's description or maybe because of my poor English skills.

So, anyway I found out the problem requires to be a integer.

Then here the correct interpretation:
Given 3 integers $2 \leq t, a, b \leq 2^{31}-1$ proof or refute that $\frac{t^a-1}{t^b-1}$ is not a integer if $a \mod b \neq 0$

Bonus: If it is possible explain it in a easy way that a cs student could comprehend.

Comment: I admire your follow-through at "getting to the bottom" of the problem, and despite a successful "pass" with your program, persisting in your efforts to seek a mathematical proof (or refutation) that explains the "why"...

Comment: **HINT** $\ $ [See here,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11636#11636) for just one of the may times this was discussed here (and more generally).

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks and in fact I have other problems that I don't know the mathematical proof but I don't remember well any of them for the exception of this one.

Comment: Also We asked (a friend and I) to a math teacher at the university for a mathematical proof for other problem and if I don't bad remember where about graphs. We got the response "Search it yourself" followed with a epic poker face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $a>b$ to make it more interesting.

Let's apply Euclid's algorithm. Write $a=qb+r$, with $0\le r<b$ and $q$ integer. Write $N=t^b-1$, so $t^b\equiv 1 \pmod{N}$. Raise this congruence to $q^{th}$ power to get the congruence $t^{qb}\equiv 1 \pmod{N}$. Multiply this by $t^r$ to get
$t^a=t^{qb+r}\equiv t^r\pmod{N}.$
So in the end we get
$$
t^a-1\equiv t^r-1\pmod{N}.
$$
Here always $t^r-1<t^b-1$, so we see that $N$ divides $t^a-1$ if and only if $r=0$. This is exactly what we wanted.

=============================

If we want more precise information, we see that Euclid's algorithm runs the distance, and we get that 
$$
gcd(t^a-1,t^b-1)=t^{gcd(a,b)}-1.
$$

Comment: @Jyrki: see the problem's constraints: $2 \leq t, a, b \leq 2^{31} - 1$.  Hence, t = 0 is not a counterexample.

Comment: Good explication even for a computer science student.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11636#11636) and its links for a more general viewpoint.

Comment: @amWhy: Sorry, my bad. I thought I saw $0$ as the lower bound for $t$. I will edit.

Comment: @Jyrki: no problem!  The fact is, you took the challenge to "make the problem more interesting", and in doing so, tackled the OP's question! No harm done!

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Sorry about that. Can't say that I would be surprised to learn about this. I just lack the familiarity with tools to check for the possibility of a re-run. I've been here only for two weeks, so I'm still learning how the place really works.

Comment: @Jyrki: No apology needed. My comment was meant merely to inform folks of other threads that may also prove insightful.